# I am unable to login "infinite login loop"

Tags: greeter

I've tried just about everything I've found suggested. Every time I put in my password, it looks like it is logging in, but then it cycles back to the password entry page.

Anyone have this issue as well and know of any fixes?

Comment: `rm .X*` in your home directory? Usually this problem is caused by `$HOME/.Xauthority` being screwed up.

Comment: Am I able to do that from the login screen? So far, any combination of ctrl+alt+F1 etc. have not worked... Would booting into a Live CD work?

Comment: You need to get to a shell somehow. Either boot GRUB into recovery mode, or if you're booting EFI, append the 'recovery' kernel parameter to the boot line.

Comment: "tried just about everything I've found suggested" - please mention what you have tried so far.Please provide links to solutions you have tried, if possible. Also are you able to login to _guest session_ ?

Comment: I have not yet tried deleting $HOME/.Xauthority. I have tried all shell access methods with no luck. I will reply back tonight to update on whether or not deleting that file works. Thank you for the support. And I disbaled the Guest session feature.

Comment: removing .Xauthority did not work.
So far all I have tried is removing .Xauthority and accessing the shell interface via the login page.
The shell interface would not show when I tried activating it and removing .Xauthority did not work as my login page is still stuck in a loop.

Comment: Does the guest account work

Answer (score 4):

Start the system, and open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type:

```
sudo rm -r $HOME/.Xauthority
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the login screen. This should solve the issue.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: OMG Haha thanks so much to user4300. I don't have the reputation to comment on the awnser but that's the only thing that worked after debugging the whole day

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F6 switches to terminal on logon screen. Ctrl+Alt+F7 goes back to logon screen. This solution is from the beginning of Linux history.