# After fglx update can't use gui

Tags: release-freya, drivers, amd

Hello so I have a AMD APU with a Radeon in it.

I installed the proprietary drivers via software sources, but I had some problems with them, so I switched back to the stock ones. A few days after that I switched back to prop drivers the same way, but this time the (updates) ones, since I need CS:GO fps ;)

That worked okay, but every startup it would take a few seconds longer than normal for the gui to show up. It did work well for some time like that.
I didn't investigate it further because way earlier I had completely broken my xorg and stuff with the AMD drivers and the script, so I was just happy it was working now.

A few minutes ago I did updates and upgrades and rebooted, after that I couldn't get into GUI again. Waiting obviously didn't work anymore, I did see that the apt-get update did update the `fglx` drivers.

So now I am stuck in console and can't even access the internet to install stuff etc. because I am using a wifi dongle. I did get it working via command line last time, but only with wep so I had to change the routers settings etc, this time I am asking you earlier so maybe I can avoid that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use WEP on your WiFi router use Ethernet instead

Comment: I know I should do that. But I don't have long ethernet cables in my new home and the bigger issue, the router is in a different room where a flatmate lives in. She is already dealing with the router and a raspberry pi that is connected to it, so that is an issue.

Comment: What happens when you run `startx`

Comment: it says Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server - xinit: connection to X server lost - waiting for X server to shut down... And I am back to Command line.

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers 
Will this also work on elementary OS?  I am afraid to try it, since last time I did stuff myself I must have made mistakes, so this time I am not touching it until I get confirmation. 
So I can access the internet now and did upgrades, but the issue still remains. If there is a way to fix the AMD drivers, I would be okay with that too, obviously.  Again, I am using 64bit freya and didn't change anything but installed the AMD proprietary drivers via additional sources/gui.
I am the same dude btw, made a new account last time since I didn't think.

Comment: So I did follow the steps in the guide and deleted the fglrx* files, but the reinstall of xorg didn't work because of dependency issues. After that I was stuck in a login loop, but the answer to this question solved that issue: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/i-am-unable-to-login-infinite-login-loop  My installation is still pretty broken I guess, but at least I can use the gui again.